# Guest Additions for Ubuntu Server guest on Windows 7 Host

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, guest-additions

At the very outset, I am a complete newbie to Virtual Box and Vagrant. I have tried finding an answer everywhere, but I am not sure I am on the right track! Any help will be appreciated!

1. My host is Windows 7, 64 bit.
2. I installed Virtual Box 4.3.22 and Vagrant 1.7.2
3. I then installed this guest from the Vagrant site: ttps://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/precise64

I know I am supposed to install guest additions - because they are important for 'providing closer integration between host and guest and improving the interactive performance of guest systems.'.

However, I am not sure how to go about this. My device menu on Virtual Box no longer appears. I saw this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/59103/why-virtualboxs-menu-has-disappeared. I tried exiting scaled mode - Host + C, but nothing happened.

What should I be doing?